# why I can't use @ in input:name with value in the back

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have really basic problem with razorpage in asp.net core. I can't use @variable in the below code:

```
<li><input type="radio" id="a1@qu.ID" name="q@qu.ID"><label for="a1 @qu.ID">@qu.a1</label></li>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is no space<sup>1</sup> before the `@`. Razor treats that as a single string.

For example, this razor:

```
@{
    var val1 = "hello";
    var val2 = "world";
}

<p>Let us say @val1 to Joe</p>
<p>The@val2 is large</p>
```

Renders to

```
Let us say hello to Joe

The@val2 is large
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/bWhYmd

You can fix that by wrapping the code after `@` in parentheses.

```
<p>The@(val2) is large</p>
```

Will render to

```
Theworld is large
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/BbeK2C

<sup>1</sup> It's not strictly a "space"; realistic it's any non alphanumeric character, though I'm not sure exactly what the actual character set is.